# Blackjack program returning cards as null?

Tags: java

Main Class:

public class Blackjack {

```
static Deck D;
static Hand P;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    init();
}

private static void init() {
    D=new Deck();
    P=new Hand(D);
    startGame();
}

private static void startGame() {
    System.out.print("Your cards are: "+P.H.get(0)+", "+P.H.get(1));
}
```

}

Hand Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Hand {
ArrayList<String> H;
Random R;
public Hand(Deck D){
    R=new Random();
    H=new ArrayList<String>();
    int C=R.nextInt(D.getP().length);
    H.add(D.getP()[C]);
    D.removeFromDeck(C);
    int E=R.nextInt(D.getP().length);
    H.add(D.getP()[E]);
    D.removeFromDeck(E);
}
```

}

Deck Class

```
public class Deck {
String[] P;
public Deck(){
    P=new String[52];
    String Suit="Default";
    int C=0;
    for(int A=1;A<=4;A++){
        switch(A){
        case 1:
            Suit="Hearts";
            break;
        case 2:
            Suit="Diamonds";
            break;
        case 3:
            Suit="Clubs";
            break;
        case 4:
            Suit="Spades";
            break;
        }
        for(int B=1;B<=13;B++){
            if(B>10){
                switch(B){
                case 11: P[C]="Joker of "+Suit; 
                break;
                case 12: P[C]="Queen of "+Suit;
                break;
                case 13: P[C]="King of "+Suit;
                break;
                }
            }else{
                P[C]=B+" of "+Suit;
            }
        }
    }
}
public void setP(String[] p) {
    P = p;
}
public String[] getP() {
    return P;
}
public void removeFromDeck(int C){
    System.arraycopy(P, C + 1, P, C,
            P.length - C - 1);
}
```

}

When I compile and run this code, it prints that my 2 cards are null, null. I have looked through the code and can't seem to find my error. Maybe you can? TY for any help you give me.

Edit: It is now returning spades only, could someone please help?

Comment: BTW. J is for Jack, not Joker. :-)

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why you haven't encapsulated the `Card` class as that would make instantiation of cards easier. The `Card` class could override the toString method to show if it is "Jack, Queen or King". Furthermore you can abstract the suit value into its own class or enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both your loops have conditions the wrong way round:

```
for(int A=1;A>=4;A++)

   ...
   for(int B=1;B>=13;B++)
```

Neither of these will execute any iterations. They should be:

```
for(int A=1;A<=4;A++)

   ...
   for(int B=1;B<=13;B++)
```

Additionally, you're not allocating enough size:

```
P=new String[51];
```

There are 52 cards in a back, not 51.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you'll always get spades with the code as posted, because your switch statement to select the suit doesn't have any breaks in. I would have expected this to result in a compile-time warning. You *really* should pay attention to warnings. You can add break statements like this:

```
switch(A) {
    case 1:
        S = "Hearts";
        break;
    case 2:
        S = "Diamonds";
        break;
    case 3:
        S = "Clubs";
        break;
    case 4:
        S = "Spades";
        break;
}
```

Finally, I would *strongly* advise you to use more meaningful variable names, preferrably following Java naming conventions. (There are actually various other changes I'd make to your code, but start off with those.)

Comment: That gives me a arrayindexoutofbounds error inside the switch statement. and also, you answer all my questions almost instantly, its almost like your stalking me D:

Comment: Ok now It is only returning spades, its really confusing because the C variable should stop it from doing that

Comment: @user1357527: You don't have a `break` statement in any of your switch conditions. Didn't you get a warning about that?

Comment: @user1357527 common convention is to start from zero (0). And for-loops are written starting from zero and then you only need to do "<" on the condition instead of "<=".

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm pretty sure Java doesn't warn about leaving out the `break` but it will in C#

Comment: @Spoike: Yes, but for card values I think it *does* make a certain amount of sense to go from 1 to 13 inclusive. Given the rest of the problems in the code, I figured it was worth leaving that bit alone for the moment :)

Comment: @user1357527: Not in the code posted you haven't. Look at where the suit is picked, and see my edit.

Comment: I added the break statements, now its back to returning null null

Comment: @user1357527: Then I suspect you've added them in the wrong place. Now would be a very good time to learn some diagnostic skills - adding logging, running the code in a debugger.

Comment: The break statments seem to be breaking the loop? How to fix?

Comment: @user1357527: Well I've shown you where they *should* be (see my edit) and I've suggested that you should be able to diagnose it on your own. I'm afraid there are limits to how much hand-holding is really useful.

Comment: That is where i had them. copyed and pasted your code to double check and ran and same result

Comment: @user1357527: Your updated code never increments `C`. You got rid of the `C++;` line for no obvious reason... and it seems that you *still* haven't learned about diagnostics or debugging.

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance the issue seems here: `for(int A=1;A>=4;A++){` and here `for(int B=1;B>=13;B++){`. These loops will never execute because in your first loop, at the first iteration A will be 1, hence being less than 4, meaning it breaks your condition for the first loop and the same applies for the second loop. Replacing the `>` with `<` should yield you something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled as to why you haven't encapsulated the `Card` class yet as it would make instantiation of cards easier. Furthermore you can always abstract suit into its own class or enum.

Anyhow, I might be doing too much of the design work for you but here are some things to get you started:

```
public enum Suit {
    Spade,
    Heart,
    Diamond,
    Club;

    public static Suit getSuit(int suit) {
        switch (suit) {
            case 3: 
                return Suit.Spade;
            case 2:
                return Suit.Heart;
            case 1:
                return Suit.Diamond;
            case 0:
            default:
                return Suit.Club;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a simple `Card` class that uses this suit.

```
public class Card {

    private Suit suit;
    private int value;

    public Card(Suit suit, int value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Card(int suit, int value) {
        this(Suit.getSuit(suit), value);
    }

    public int getValue() { return value; }
    public Suit getSuit() { return suit; }

}
```

Creating the deck is simple. Here is a simple factory to get you started:

```
public class DeckFactory {

    public static List<Card> BuildDeck() {
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

        for (int value = 1; value <= 13; ++value) {
            for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; ++suit) {
                cards.add(new Card(value, suit));
            }
        }

        return cards;
    }

}
```

I leave the actual implementation of putting it into a `Deck` or `Hand` class for yourself. In your `Card` class you can override the `toString()` method to return a better string representation of the Card object.

```
// in Card.java
@override
public String toString() {

   String output = "";

   switch(this.value) {
       1: 
           output += "Ace ";
           break;
       11: 
           output += "Jack ";
           break;
       12: 
           output += "Queen ";
           break;
       13: 
           output += "King ";
           break;
       default:
           output += this.value;
           break;
   }

   output += " of ";

   output += this.suit.toString();
       // returns the name of the enum

   return output;

}
```

Hope this helps out.